# searching for multiple strings in multiple files in PowerShell

Tags: arrays, powershell, search

first of all, I've got a reliable search (thanks to some help on Stack Overflow) that checks for occurrences of different strings in a line over many log files.

I've now been tasked to include multiple searches and since there are about 20 files and about a dozen search criteria, I don't want to to have to access these files over 200 times. I believe the best way of doing this is in a array, but so far all methods I've tried have failed.

The search criteria is made up of date, which obviously changes very day, a fixed string (ERROR) and a unique java classname. Here is what i have:

```
        $dateStr = Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd"
        $errword = 'ERROR'
        $word01 = [regex]::Escape('java.util.exception')   
    
        $pattern01 = "${dateStr}.+${errword}.+${word01}"
    
        $count01 = (Get-ChildItem -Filter $logdir -Recurse | Select-String -Pattern $pattern01 -AllMatches |ForEach-Object Matches |Measure-Object).Count
        Add-Content $outfile  "$dateStr,$word01,$count01"
```

the easy way to expand this is to have a separate three command entry (set word, set pattern and then search) for each class i want to search against - which I've done and it works, but its not elegant and then we're processing >200 files to run the search. I've tried to read the java classes in from a simple text file with mixed results, but its the only thing I've been able to get to work in order to simplify the search for 12 different patterns.

Comment: have you tried generating all your combined patterns from your input sources, building a regex OR, and using that in your `S-S` call? ///// also, the `-Path` parameter of `S-S` will read lines in far faster than using `G-C` and a pipeline stage. [*grin*]

Comment: The `-Pattern` of [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string) supports a string array. Try this: `'One Two Three' |Select-String -Pattern 'One', 'Three'`, and this: `'Two Three Four' |Select-String -Pattern 'One', 'Three'` (Either of the two search patterns matches both input lines.) In other words, you can just do: `... |Select-String -Pattern $pattern01, $pattern02, $pattern03` (which means: select the string that matches `$pattern01` or `$pattern02` or `$pattern03`.

Answer (score 1):

[iRon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1701026/iron) provided an important pointer: [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string) can accept an *array* of patterns to search for, and reports matches for lines that match *any one* of them.

You can then get away with a *single* `Select-String` call, combined with a [`Group-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object) call that allows you to group all matching lines by which pattern matched:

```
# Create the input file with class names to search for.
@'
java.util.exception
java.util.exception2
'@ > classNames.txt

# Construct the array of search patterns,
# and add them to a map (hashtable) that maps each
# pattern to the original class name.
$dateStr = Get-Date -Format 'yyyy-MM-dd'
$patternMap = [ordered] @{}
Get-Content classNames.txt | ForEach-Object {
  $patternMap[('{0}.+{1}.+{2}' -f $dateStr, 'ERROR', [regex]::Escape($_))] = $_
}

# Search across all files, using multiple patterns.
Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse $logdir | Select-String @($patternMap.Keys) |
  # Group matches by the matching pattern.
  Group-Object Pattern |
    # Output the result; send to `Set-Content` as needed.
    ForEach-Object { '{0},{1},{2}' -f $dateStr, $patternMap[$_.Name], $_.Count }
```

Note:

- `$logDir`, as the name suggests, is presumed to refer to a *directory* in which to (recursively) search for log files; passing that to `-Filter` wouldn't work, so I've removed it (which then positionally binds `$logDir` to the `-Path` parameter); `-File` limits the results to *files*; if other types of files are also present, add a `-Filter` argument as needed, e.g. `-Filter *.log`
- `Select-String`'s `-AllMatches` switch is generally *not* required - you only need it if any of the patterns can match multiple times *per line* and you want to capture all of those matches.
- Using `@(...)`, the [array-subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#array-subexpression-operator--) around the collection of the hashtable's keys, `$patternMap.Keys`, i.e. the search patterns, is required purely for technical reasons: it forces the collection to be convertible to an array of strings (`[string[]]`), which is how the `-Pattern` parameter is typed.

  - The need for `@(...)` is surprising, and may be indicative of a bug, as of PowerShell 7.2; see [GitHub issue #16061](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/16061).